# How to immediately stop a running DbContext.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am currently developing a service. Services have limited time to shut down (4s).

I have a shutdown procedure, and this also pushes some minor data via EF6 to an sql database.

...

shutdown!

Step1 (stops normal operation)

step2 pushes some shutdown data to the db

step3 Final shutdown, dispose all etc.

The app has more than one context, and one execution strategy that is set in a way that it retries for about a minute. I'd like to keep that this way.

Now it may so happen that the database is down - and thus this call to the database takes a long time, maximum 1 minute because of the execution policy.

This is way over the 4s and so i would like to have an option to immediately stop the action. I cannot ask for more time.

So far i have tried the SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken); but this still continues execution for a minute, cancelling the token does nothing. I then tried using a second Task to call dispose on the context, close the connection, etc. This sometimes seemed to work, but in other cases this still waits a minute before throwing an exception.

```
var timeoutTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        context.Database.Connection.Close();
                        Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:G} {nameof(cancellationToken)} token is canceled!");
                        using(context) { }
                        return;
                    }

                    Task.Delay(10, timeoutTaskTokenSource.Token).Wait(timeoutTaskTokenSource.Token);
                    
                    timeoutTaskTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }, cancellationToken);
```

Right now i am thinking about creating a thread and aborting it, however i hope i can find a more sensible solution.

EDIT:

Connection timeout is set in the connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=False;User ID=someuser;Password=somepassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=1;Application ame=somename;ConnectRetryCount=0;ConnectRetryInterval=1
```

The command timeout is set to 1 aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is unavailable you could use the [Connection Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout) property of your connection string. This will abort the connection attempt after the delay.

If you wantn to abort a command you could use the [CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout) property.

```
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 5;
```

Comment: and CommandTimeout ? what is the actual exception and after what delay does it come from ?

Comment: both are set to 1. The exception comes from the fact that the dbcontext cannot reach the database  (provider failed to open)